# Check specific column in datatable is blank

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable like below:

```
   ID           DBName         Path                      Status
    1           Test          F:\Backup\test.bak
    2           Learning      F:\Backup\Learning.bak 
    3           NewTool       F:\Backup\NewToolt.bak
```

I need to verify whether the whole column 'Status' is blank or not..
If the column 'Status' is blank then I want to remove it from the datatable.

Comment: Where do the data in the table come from? How do you access the table?

Comment: @marsh-wiggle : I execute a script and will get the data from SQL and then will add another filed Status to check backup physical location,

Comment: Note: Null and blank are two different things

Answer (score 1):

One of the many ways to check this would be

```
SELECT Status, count(*) FROM DataTable 
WHERE Status IS NOT null
GROUP BY Status
```

If you get back a count, then you got non-null data. Else the column is null in every row.
You can use/extend the same logic for Blank values ( length = 0 ) as well